# Syntax in sorting code Python

Tags: python

what I'm supposed to do is to

> Write a function top_k that takes a list of students and an integer k and 
>   returns a list of the names of the k students with the highest scores in 
>   alphabetical order. If there are students in the range (k + 1, · · · k + i) who 
>   have the same score as the kth student, include them in the list as well.

such that when I input

```
top_k(student_list1, 5) 
>>> [('eugene', 'A', 21), ('simon', 'A', 21), ('john', 'A', 15), ('tiffany', 'A', 15), ('dave', 'B', 12)]
top_k(student_list2, 3)
>>>[('eugene', 'A', 21), ('simon', 'A', 21), ('john', 'A', 15), ('tiffany', 'A', 15)]
```

where the

```
student_list1 = [('tiffany', 'A', 15),
            ('jane', 'B', 10),
            ('ben', 'C', 8),
            ('simon', 'A', 21),
            ('eugene', 'A', 21),
            ('john', 'A', 15),
            ('jimmy', 'F', 1),
            ('charles', 'C', 9),
            ('freddy', 'D', 4),
            ('dave', 'B', 12)]


student_list2 = [('tiffany', 'A', 15),
            ('jane', 'B', 10),
            ('ben', 'C', 8),
            ('john', 'A', 15),
            ('simon', 'A', 21),
            ('eugene', 'A', 21)]
```

My code is

```
def top_k(students, k):
    toptobottom = sorted(students, key = lambda x: x[2], reverse = True)
    takeout= toptobottom[:k+1]
    result = []
    for takethat in takeout:
        if takethat[2] == 21:
        result.append(takethat)
            result.sort( key= lambda x: x[0])
        elif takethat[2] ==15:
            result.append(takethat)
    return result
```

I am unsure of where to place the result.sort( key ..). Should it be in the same line as elif, or should there be an indentation?
Thanks!

Comment: Hard to be sure, but I'm fairly certain that whoever set this task didn't want you hardcoding the top scores!

Comment: What `for` loop do in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This by no means in an answer, so I really don't want it to be marked as such, but there are a couple of things I wanted to chip in on that were too long for a comment that might be really helpful to you in the long run.

With regards to your question:

```
def top_k(students, k):
    toptobottom = sorted(students, key = lambda x: x[2], reverse = True)
    takeout= toptobottom[:k+1]
    result = []
    for takethat in takeout:
        if takethat[2] == 21:
            result.append(takethat)  # I indented this
            result.sort( key= lambda x: x[0])
        elif takethat[2] ==15:
            result.append(takethat)
    return result
```

I think I fixed your indentation for you, but I haven't analyzed any of your logic. I saw hardcoded scores and stopped reading, because **that's a really bad idea to do**. Don't do that, ever ever ever ever. Especially when you're doing homework for an algorithms class or something.

The second thing is, I don't think you should totally ignore some of the python resources out there, [python's standard library resource for sorting is enormous](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) and there are a lot of libraries out there that can help you.

Thirdly,  a lot of effort was spent providing a kind of completeness into python's libraries and [built in types that I really think you should check out](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

Fourthly, I prepared a couple little snippets according to your example. Of course, I didn't make it all nice into a single function for you, because I want you to think about what you're doing. I think you'll find this very helpful, regardless.

```
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter
from copy import deepcopy

student_list1 = [('tiffany', 'A', 15),
            ('jane', 'B', 10),
            ('ben', 'C', 8),
            ('simon', 'A', 21),
            ('eugene', 'A', 21),
            ('john', 'A', 15),
            ('jimmy', 'F', 1),
            ('charles', 'C', 9),
            ('freddy', 'D', 4),
            ('dave', 'B', 12)]

def get_sorted(student_list):
    q = sorted(student_list1, key=itemgetter(2,0), reverse=True)
    # Now that the list is sorted according to score and
    # name reversed, (meaning that while simon and eugene
    # will both be at the top, simon will always come first
    # we need to swap nearby names according to their value.
    for i in xrange(0, len(q)-1):
        if q[i][0] > q[i+1][0] and q[i][2] is q[i+1][2]:
            temp = q[i+1]
            q[i+1] = q[i]
            q[i]   = temp
    return q

print 'correct sorted order'
for i in get_sorted(student_list1):
    print i


q = get_sorted(student_list1)
our_dict = dict.fromkeys( [x[2] for x in q], [] )
for i in q:
    our_dict[i[2]] = our_dict[i[2]] + [i]

print 'grouped together'
print our_dict

# this gets some number of records from the dict
# according to the specifications of your program
def get_some(number):
    buff = []
    for i in sorted(our_dict.keys(), reverse=True):
        if len(buff) < number:
            buff += our_dict[i]

    return buff

print "let's get \'five\' elements from the list, like in your example"
print get_some(5)
print
print "let's get \'three\' elements from the list, like in your example"
print get_some(3)
```

Here's the output:

```
correct sorted order
('eugene', 'A', 21)
('simon', 'A', 21)
('john', 'A', 15)
('tiffany', 'A', 15)
('dave', 'B', 12)
('jane', 'B', 10)
('charles', 'C', 9)
('ben', 'C', 8)
('freddy', 'D', 4)
('jimmy', 'F', 1)
grouped together
{1: [('jimmy', 'F', 1)], 4: [('freddy', 'D', 4)], 8: [('ben', 'C', 8)], 9: [('charles', 'C', 9)], 10: [('jane', 'B', 10)], 12: [('dave', 'B', 12)], 15: [('john', 'A', 15), ('tiffany', 'A', 15)], 21: [('eugene', 'A', 21), ('simon', 'A', 21)]}

let's get 'five' elements from the list, like in your example
[('eugene', 'A', 21), ('simon', 'A', 21), ('john', 'A', 15), ('tiffany', 'A', 15), ('dave', 'B', 12)]

let's get 'three' elements from the list, like in your example
[('eugene', 'A', 21), ('simon', 'A', 21), ('john', 'A', 15), ('tiffany', 'A', 15)]
```

Think you can synthesize all of this together and complete your assignment with a better understanding? There are a couple of complex things going on in here, such as dicts, lists, and list comprehensions, but I think it's a nice compilation of the features that allow python to make **mince meat** out of pretty much every list problem there is.

Comment: Thanks for the links and help!!

Comment: @user3251511, you're very welcome! Be sure to upvote the answers that were helpful and mark the solution you used as an answer, so the people that contributed to this question get points for their answer.

Comment: Will do! Finally got my reputations points up to 15. Now I can start voting. Hhahaha

Comment: Upvotes from me! Good job & welcome to stack overflow, @user3251511!

Answer (score 1):

As well as your indentation problem, your code is being written specifically for the input data (i.e. top scores hard-coded in your function). Although this might get you through the exercise, it is not good practice and you should think more generally about the problem you are trying to solve.

In pseudocode:

```
def top_k(students, k):
    create a blank output list
    for each student in the list of students sorted in reverse order by score:
        if either ((we have fewer than k students in the output so far) or 
                   (the student equals the score of the last student in output)):
            add the student to the output
        otherwise:
            stop looping
    return the output sorted by name
```

Comment: I'd appreciate an explanation for the downvote, so I can try to improve my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can sort input array just once and then select right students.

```
def top_k(students, k):
    toptobottom = sorted(students, key = lambda x: (-x[2], x[0]))
    length = len(toptobottom)
    if k >= 0 and k < length:
        result = toptobottom[:k]
        i = k
    else:
        result = toptobottom
        i = 0
        k = 1
    while i < length and toptobottom[i][2] == toptobottom[k-1][2]:
        result.append(toptobottom[i])
        i += 1
    return result
```